# Get file (401 unauthorized) - Alfresco

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I get a file in Alfresco, with link for example: http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/workspace/SpacesStore/c9d187e8-aec5-4177-9587-a5b924e514cd/exemplo.pdf with XMLHttpRequest on javascript and I don't have problems. But i'm trying to do this on JAVA:

```
public static byte[] callURL(String myURL) {
        System.out.println("Requeted URL:" + myURL);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        URLConnection urlConn = null;
        InputStreamReader in = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(myURL);

            urlConn = url.openConnection();
            if (urlConn != null)
                urlConn.setReadTimeout(60 * 1000);
            if (urlConn != null && urlConn.getInputStream() != null) {
                in = new InputStreamReader(urlConn.getInputStream(),
                        Charset.defaultCharset());
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(in);
                if (bufferedReader != null) {
                    int cp;
                    while ((cp = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
                        sb.append((char) cp);
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                }
            }
            in.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Exception while calling URL:" + myURL, e);
        }
        String sbString = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(sbString);
        byte[] b = sbString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
        return b;
    }
```

But this gives to me

> 401 unauthorized

. What is the problem? I need any authentication ? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If /share/proxy/alfresco/ works for you means you have an active Share connection. With Java you need to authenticate separately against Alfresco repository.

Comment: How can I do that?  I dont understand.

Comment: I don't want to give a username or password, I want to receive this parameters... Or another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! For people who may have the same problem, follow this [tutorial](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/NodeRef_cookbook#Getting_a_NodeRef_from_its_path). You have, inclusive, how to access the content.

**Plain text:**

```
ContentReader reader = contentService.getReader(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
String content = reader.getContentString();
```

**Binary data:**

```
ContentReader reader = contentService.getReader(nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
InputStream originalInputStream = reader.getContentInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final int BUF_SIZE = 1 << 8; //1KiB buffer
byte[] buffer = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
int bytesRead = -1;
while((bytesRead = originalInputStream.read(buffer)) > -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
}
originalInputStream.close();
byte[] binaryData = outputStream.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Patricia, please post here the main information from the tutorial just in case the link you provided becomes dead